# Replace URLs (starting with http, https, www) in text with links to URLs

Tags: html, regex, python-3.x, url, hyperlink

I have text which contains URLS starting with http, https and www. for example,

```
text = "I want to open up www.google.com"
```

How can I convert `www.google.com` to its corresponding URL link in the same text?

I looked at https://gist.github.com/guillaumepiot/4539986. The `# Replace url to link` example works perfectly for URLS starting with `http` and `https`. How can I modify the regular expression in this example to work for URLs starting with `www`. Also, how will the corresponding `HTML` change?

I found many similar questions on the Internet but none of the answers to those questions worked for my case.

Comment: Can you specify with an example? What you exactly need?

Answer (score 0):

The regex is:

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/
```

For more info, see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8234912/4626943

Comment: How will the corresponding `HTML` change?